# Why javascript doesn't detect the elements that are added after a django for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

So it's all in the title, I'll put my code right here:

```html
{% extends "list/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<main class="site-main" style="background-color: black;">

    <!--Banner Area-->
    <section class="site-banner pb-5" style="background-color: black; overflow: hidden; position: relative; color: white;">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>Liste</h3>
            <p class="total" style="color: black; display: none;">{{ total }}</p>
            {% for movie in movies %}
                <div class="c">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1481" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                    <div class="overlay">
                    <a data-modal-target="#cont" class="icon" title="User Profile" style="display: block;">
                    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="cont{{movie.id}}" id="cont{{movie.id}}">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1481" alt="Avatar" class="image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <div class="title">{{ movie.title }}</div>
                                
                                <a data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</a>
                            </div>
                            <span>Sorti en {{ movie.date_released|date:"Y" }}</span> <span>avec {{ movie.author}}</span> <span class="id">{{movie.id}}</span>
                            <p>{{movie.synopsis}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

            <div id="ov"></div>

        </div>
    </section>
</main>






<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]');
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]');
const overlay = document.getElementById('ov');
var d = document.querySelector('.total').innerText;
function popup() {
  for (i=1, c = d; i<c; i++) {
  const cont = addEventListener(document.querySelector(".cont"+i));
  console.log(cont);
  cont.style.background = "red";
  cont.style.color = "white";
  cont.style.width = "75%";
  cont.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0)";
  cont.style.position = "fixed";
  cont.style.top = "50%";
  cont.style.left = "50%";
  cont.style.padding = "20px";
  cont.style.zindex = "10";
  cont.style.overflow = "hidden";
  cont.style.maxWidth = "80%";
  cont.style.borderRadius = "30px";
  const contAct = document.querySelectorAll(".cont"+i+".active");
  contAct.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)";
  contAct.style.display = "block";
    openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget);
      openModal(modal);
    })
  })

  overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modals = document.querySelectorAll(cont+".active");
    modals.forEach(modal => {
      closeModal(modal);
    })
  })

  closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const modal = button.closest(cont);
      closeModal(modal);
    })
  })


  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
      const modals = document.querySelectorAll(cont+".active");
    modals.forEach(modal => {
      closeModal(modal);
    })
    }
  });

  function openModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return
    modal.classList.add('active');
    overlay.classList.add('active');
  }

  function closeModal(modal) {
    if (modal == null) return
    modal.classList.remove('active');
    overlay.classList.remove('active');
  }
}
}


</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

When I add to my div, "{{ movie.id}}" to make cont1, cont2... in my javascript script, it adds to my div, the desired css properties except that it doesn't do anything and I don't understand why.
I hope you'll be able to help me, if you have more info, don't hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem

```
const cont = addEventListener(document.querySelector(".cont"+i));


const cont = document.querySelector(".cont"+i);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work, do you have another solution?